UDP Device Discovery Not Working on Windows with Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter app that aims to enable devices to discover each other by continuously sending and receiving UDP packets. The specific functions are as follows:
On Android devices, other Android devices can be discovered.
On Windows devices, I can't discover other devices, but I can discover Windows devices from Android devices.
I've tried the following solutions:
Windows Firewall is turned off, and firewall exceptions are set.
Turned off third-party antivirus software.
Despite the above, the problem persists.
My expectation is that Windows and Android devices can achieve mutual device discovery via UDP.
Here's my code implementation:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io'; // Only for non-Web platforms
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'file_select_page.dart'; // Ensure to import file_select_page

class TransferPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TransferPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TransferPageState createState() => _TransferPageState();
}

class _TransferPageState extends State<TransferPage> {
  List<Map<String, String>> devices = [];
  bool isScanning = false;
  late RawDatagramSocket receiver;
  Timer? scanTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startListening();
    scanNetwork(); // Start scanning on initialization
  }

  Future<void> startListening() async {
    receiver = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 22473);
    receiver.listen((RawSocketEvent event) async {
      if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
        Datagram? datagram = receiver.receive();
        if (datagram != null) {
          _handleReceivedData(datagram);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void _handleReceivedData(Datagram datagram) async {
    try {
      final message = utf8.decode(datagram.data, allowMalformed: true);
      final ip = datagram.address.address;

      if (ip != await _getCurrentIP()) {
        final parts = message.split(';');
        String deviceBrand = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1].replaceFirst('Brand:', '') : 'Unknown Brand';
        String deviceModel = parts.length > 2 ? parts[2].replaceFirst('Model:', '') : 'Unknown Model';

        // Deduplication check
        if (!devices.any((device) => device['ip'] == ip)) {
          setState(() {
            devices.add({
              'ip': ip,
              'port': '22473',
              'status': 'Responded',
              'brand': deviceBrand,
              'model': deviceModel
            });
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to decode data: $e'); // Handle decode failure
    }
  }

  Future<void> scanNetwork() async {
    setState(() {
      isScanning = true;
      devices.clear(); // Clear device list for new scan
    });

    if (kIsWeb) {
      // Logic for Web platform
      return; // Broadcasting not supported on Windows for now
    } else {
      // Get current IP on non-Web platforms (like Windows)
      String? wifiIP = await _getCurrentIP();
      if (wifiIP == null) {
        setState(() {
          isScanning = false;
        });
        return;
      }

      String broadcastAddress = await getBroadcastAddress(wifiIP);

      // Start periodic broadcasting
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
        await sendBroadcast(broadcastAddress); // Use dynamically calculated broadcast address
      });

      // Set scan timeout
      scanTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), stopScanning);
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendBroadcast(String address) async {
    String message;

    // Use Platform property only on non-Web platforms
    if (Platform.isWindows) {
      message = 'Hello from Windows;Brand:Windows;Model:PC';
    } else {
      String deviceBrand = await _getDeviceBrand();
      String deviceModel = await _getDeviceModel();
      message = 'Hello from Flutter;Brand:$deviceBrand;Model:$deviceModel';
    }

    RawDatagramSocket sender = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
    sender.send(utf8.encode(message), InternetAddress(address), 22473); // Send to specified address
    sender.close();
  }

  Future<String?> _getCurrentIP() async {
    final info = NetworkInfo();
    return await info.getWifiIP();
  }

  Future<String> _getDeviceBrand() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String brand = "Unknown Brand";

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      brand = androidInfo.brand!;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      brand = iosInfo.utsname.machine!;
    }

    return brand;
  }

  Future<String> _getDeviceModel() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String model = "Unknown Model";

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      model = androidInfo.model!;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      model = iosInfo.utsname.machine!;
    }

    return model;
  }

  Future<String> getBroadcastAddress(String ip) async {
    List<String> parts = ip.split('.');
    return '${parts[0]}.${parts[1]}.${parts[2]}.255'; // Assuming subnet mask is 255.255.255.0
  }

  void stopScanning() {
    setState(() {
      isScanning = false;
    });
    scanTimer?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    receiver.close();
    scanTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('File Transfer'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              scanNetwork();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isScanning
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: devices.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // Navigate to file_select_page on tapping device
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => TransferFilesPage(
                    deviceName: devices[index]['brand'] ?? 'Unknown Brand',
                    deviceIp: devices[index]['ip'] ?? 'Unknown IP',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(devices[index]['ip'] ?? 'Unknown IP'),
                        Text('Port: 22473'),
                        Text('Status: ${devices[index]['status'] ?? 'Unknown'}'),
                        Text('Brand: ${devices[index]['brand'] ?? 'Unknown Brand'}'),
                        Text('Model: ${devices[index]['model'] ?? 'Unknown Model'}'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Desired solution:
How can I successfully discover other devices on the Windows side? How do I debug and fix this? Thank you so much!

Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/nsd which purports to handle peer discovery across ios, android, macos, and windows.
